# Lync Administration - how to set everyones presence viewable by all as default

Tags: default, office365, administration, lync, user-presence

I am using Office 365 and Microsoft Lync 2013

The menu item I am interested in setting as default upon new installation is:

```
Go to <gear icon> --> Tools --> Options --> Status
```

There are two radio buttons concerning presence on this screen. They are:

1. I want everyone to be able to see my presence
2. I want only people in contacts to be able to see my presence

Currently, when a new user installs office 365 and downloads lync, the default option they have set is number 2. What I want is:

- I want all new users to default to option 1.
- I want to apply option 1 to all existing users retrospectively.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported by office 365. This setting is controlled from the user client can cannot be set globally. Details in the post below:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/257808.aspx